# Regular Expression patterns in Oracle SQL developer: include numbers

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find the pattern using oracle sql developer. Include numbers that are `"x0000"," 0000",".0000"`

```
AND REGEXP_INSTR(string=>FTP.TEXT, pattern=>'[x]\d\d\d\d\s', match_parameter=>'i')
```

Comment: Show us the sample data and expected output. Your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
where REGEXP_LIKE(str,'[x.[:space:]]\d{4}','i')
```

The `[x.[:space:]]\d{4}` expression matches `x`, `.` or any whitespace, then any four digit characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` as follows:

```
SQL> --sample data
SQL> with your_data(id,str) as
  2  (select 1, 'x0000' from dual union all
  3  select 2, '.0000' from dual union all
  4  select 3, ' 0000'from dual union all
  5  select 4, '0000' from dual) -- this should not be in the result
  6  -- your query starts from here
  7  select * from your_data
  8  where REGEXP_like(str,'[x| |\.][0-9]{4}','i');

        ID STR
---------- -----
         1 x0000
         2 .0000
         3  0000

SQL>
```